# Text not resizing with @media rule

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Hlo im new to stackoverflow .
In my website , when i was trying to make it responsive with @media rule , its size is not changing. But other properties like color is working for me with media rule .
Can anyone help me with this ?

CSS CODE

```
@media (orientation: portrait) { 
  h2{
    font-size : 10px;
  }
 }
```

HTML CODE

```
  <h2 style="padding-top: 300px;font-size:70px;" class="text-center"><u>MERRY CHRISTMAS</u></h2>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its due to the inline css inline css will take highest priority. If you define inline css rule inside `<style>` tag or a different css file it will work.

```css
h2{
  font-size:70px
}
@media (orientation: portrait) {
  h2{
    font-size : 10px;
  }
 }
```

```html
<h2>Merry Christmas</h2>
```

or else if you want to keep inline css, just add `!important`, as added below.

```css
@media (orientation: portrait) {
  h2{
    font-size : 10px!important;
  }
 }
```

which is generally not a good practice